# Wordpress : Problem to load a file in a custom page in admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to create a plugin to add a page in admin menu. In this page, I want to select a file and do some stuff on it.
I have created a simple custom page with a file upload field and a submit button but I can't manage the submit button action. If someone can give me some ideas...

Thanks to Krishna, I add an action in the form, but when I click on submit button, I can see the first message on my code ("I read the file...") but not the second ("File is filled").

Any ideas please?

Here is my plugin file defintion : fileuploadplugin.php :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  File upload Plugin
Description:  Plugin for uploading file
Version:      1.0
License:      GPL2
License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
     die;
}

/*
    Action for menu definition
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'fileuploadplugin_menu');

/*
    Menu definition
*/
function fileuploadplugin_menu () {
    add_menu_page('File upload plugin', 'File upload', 'manage_options', 'fileuploadlogin', 'file_upload_plugin_page' );
}

/*
    Display a page with file input field and submit button
*/
function file_upload_plugin_page () {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // actions to do on the file : read it, manage it, and so on
        echo "I read the file and do what I have to do !";
        if(isset($_FILES['filetoupload'])) {
            echo "File is filed, I can read it!";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Upload file</h1>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type='file' id='filetoupload' name='File to upload : '></input>
        <?php submit_button('Upload file') ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: I tested your code and it prints `"File is filed, I can read it!"`

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code to return to same page after form submitted.

```
<form action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Updated:**

Change below line

```
if(isset($_FILES['fichier_resultat'])) {
```

to

```
if(isset($_FILES['filetoupload'])) {
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have modified my code as asked. I also add a test after the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) to test if a file has been selected : (isset($_FILES['fichier_resultat'])){ echo "OK file filed";} but this message is not displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks for your help.

The problem was in fact in the input file definition : I have used 2 different values for id and name parameters.
So I changed its definition from

```
<input type='file' id='filetoupload' name='File to upload : '></input>
```

to

```
<input type='file' id='filetoupload' name='filetoupload'></input>
```

Thanks again for you help!